# Passing two parameters at c++ lambda expression

Tags: c++

I wanted to get a subset of vector having the same keyword in the vector.
The code below works well, if I give the fixed keyword.

```
auto category_matched = [](Product &p) {
    std::string str_return;
    p.GetInfo(kINFO_CATEGORY, str_return);
    return str_return == "keyword"; 
};

std::copy_if(list_.begin(), list_.end(), 
             std::back_inserter(products), 
             category_matched);
```

Then I tried replacing "keyword" with string variable, which resulted in error.

```
auto category_matched = [](Product &p, std::string keyword) {
    std::string str_return;
    p.GetInfo(kINFO_CATEGORY, str_return);
    return str_return == keyword; 
};

std::copy_if(list_.begin(), list_.end(), 
             std::back_inserter(products), 
             category_matched);
```

Some of the error messages are like this:

```
error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at /Users/src/productset.cpp:128:29)'
        if (__pred(*__first))

note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

How can I add string variable to the function?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a function that takes `keyword` and returns a function that tests elements against that keyword?

Comment: just let the keyword be capture by the lambda, dont try to make it an argument

Comment: `[&keyword](Product &p) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

capture the keyword

```
std::string keyword = "froodle";
auto category_matched = [&keyword](Product &p) {
    std::string str_return;
    p.GetInfo(kINFO_CATEGORY, str_return);
    return str_return == keyword; 
};
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

[`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) expects a `UnaryPredicate`. That is to say, it expects a function that takes *one* argument.

You are supplying a lambda that takes *two* arguments. That is the source of the error.

Comment: This answer explains *why* the error occurs, but not *how* to fix it.